# Pandas replace values in datetime column without changing the datetime64 data type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe where I have a datetime64[ns] data type column, I want to apply a criteria that if the date is beyond a certain year it should take a fixed date I provide. Like "If the date is beyond this point, max it out to this date"

I have noticed that if I select one element from any datetime64[ns] column it's of type `pd.Timestamp`, so I thought I would pass my fixed date with the same datatype to preserve the entire column data type

But no matter how I pass that fixed date (pd.Timestamp or as as datetime.datetime) it always casts my datetime64 column into an `object` data type and gives me a epoch in nanoseconds.

My question is, how can I use np.where to substitute certain values in a dataframe if they met a condition without altering the original column type, assuming the inserted new values are of the same type of the column.

Here's an example

```
#generate some data
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[datetime.now() for i in range(10)]})
#The previous line generated a column named a with datetime64[ns]
# data type if you look at df.dtypes

df.loc[0,'a']=datetime(2050,1,1)
#In the previous line I already substitued a value by directly
# accessing its index, and it does preserve the data type datetime64[ns].
# This is the data


a
0   2050-01-01 00:00:00.000000
1   2023-08-01 17:29:59.011984
2   2023-08-01 17:29:59.011984
3   2023-08-01 17:29:59.011984
4   2023-08-01 17:29:59.011984
5   2023-08-01 17:29:59.011984
6   2023-08-01 17:29:59.011984
7   2023-08-01 17:29:59.011984
8   2023-08-01 17:29:59.011984
9   2023-08-01 17:29:59.011984

#I want to top the date until today's date if the year exceeds the present year
df['a']=np.where(df['a'].dt.year>2023,datetime.now(),df['a'])
#In the previous line, I substitued values but accessing to them
#  conditionally with an np.where The result of this 
# changes column 'a' data type into integer and puts unix epochs,
# yet the inserted data looks like datetime, this is the output


    a
0   2023-08-01 17:31:48.560111
1   1690910999011984000
2   1690910999011984000
3   1690910999011984000
4   1690910999011984000
5   1690910999011984000
6   1690910999011984000
7   1690910999011984000
8   1690910999011984000
9   1690910999011984000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [173]: from datetime import datetime
In [174]: df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[datetime.now() for i in range(10)]})
     ...: df.loc[0,'a']=datetime(2050,1,1)
In [175]: df
Out[175]: 
                           a
0 2050-01-01 00:00:00.000000
1 2023-08-01 22:01:32.599755
2 2023-08-01 22:01:32.599756
3 2023-08-01 22:01:32.599758
...
9 2023-08-01 22:01:32.599765
In [176]:  df.dtypes
Out[176]: 
a    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
In [177]: df.loc[0,'a']
Out[177]: Timestamp('2050-01-01 00:00:00')
In [178]: type(_)
Out[178]: pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp
```

So it looks like `pandas` has converted the `datetime` object into a `np.datetime64[ns]` value.  And when 'extracted' it shows a `Timestamp`.

Extracted as a numpy array:

```
In [181]: df['a'].values
Out[181]: 
array(['2050-01-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2023-08-01T22:01:32.599755000',
       '2023-08-01T22:01:32.599756000', '2023-08-01T22:01:32.599758000',
        ...],
      dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

Explore the `where` without assignment:

```
In [182]: np.where(df['a'].dt.year>2023,datetime.now(),df['a'])
Out[182]: 
array([datetime.datetime(2023, 8, 1, 22, 4, 1, 660226),
       1690927292599755000, 1690927292599756000, 1690927292599758000,
       1690927292599759000, 1690927292599760000, 1690927292599761000,
       1690927292599762000, 1690927292599763000, 1690927292599765000],
      dtype=object)
```

`where` combines values the `datatime64` array, and the `datetime` object, resulting in an object dtype array.

```
In [183]: np.where(df['a'].dt.year>2023,datetime.now(),df['a'].values)
```

Using the `values` doesn't make a difference.

But lets look at the datatime` object more:

```
In [184]: datetime.now()
Out[184]: datetime.datetime(2023, 8, 1, 22, 4, 45, 741794)
In [185]: np.datetime64(datetime.now())
Out[185]: numpy.datetime64('2023-08-01T22:05:10.714725')
```

Now if we use `where` with `datatime64` elements in both arguments:

```
In [187]: np.where(df['a'].dt.year>2023,np.datetime64(datetime.now()),df['a'])
Out[187]: 
array(['2023-08-01T22:06:06.657836000', '2023-08-01T22:01:32.599755000',
       '2023-08-01T22:01:32.599756000', '2023-08-01T22:01:32.599758000',
       ...],
      dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

Now we can assign that back to dataframe:

```
In [189]: df['b']=np.where(df['a'].dt.year>2023,np.datetime64(datetime.now()),df['a'])
In [190]: df
Out[190]: 
                           a                          b
0 2050-01-01 00:00:00.000000 2023-08-01 22:06:46.833972
1 2023-08-01 22:01:32.599755 2023-08-01 22:01:32.599755
2 2023-08-01 22:01:32.599756 2023-08-01 22:01:32.599756
3 2023-08-01 22:01:32.599758 2023-08-01 22:01:32.599758
...
```

So while simply assigning a `datetime` object to the dataframe cell forces a conversion to `datetime64`, to get the same thing to work with `where`, we have do an explicit conversion first.

Answer (score 1):

This problem happens because you're mixing pandas and numpy, and they have different notions of datetime types.  You need to use pandas to do your filtering:

```
df.loc[df['a'].dt.year>2023,'a'] = datetime.now()
```

Comment: How best I can use pandas only for nested np.where, like if I have column `A` as an integer and if it's greater than 10 I wanto to put hte value on column `B`. But if column `B` is greater than 100 then I want to use `C` instead.... but if `C` is .... so on, so on.

Comment: I typically use `df['col']=np.where(df['A']>10,np.where(df['B']>100,np.where(df['C']>1000,1000,df['C']),df['B']),df['A'])`

In other words: If then elif then, elif then, elif then, else....

Comment: That kind of code works perfectly fine for integer and float types, but once you bring in datetimes, it falls apart.  numpy sees the datetimes as long integers, and passes the data back as long integers.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're encountering is related to the data type consistency when using the `np.where` function. When you mix different data types within a single column, Pandas might promote the entire column to a more general data type that can accommodate all the values, leading to the observed behavior.

To achieve your goal of updating the values conditionally while preserving the data type of the column, you can use the `apply` function along with a custom function that returns either the original datetime or the fixed date based on your condition. This approach will ensure that the data type of the column remains unchanged.

Here's how you can do it:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

# Generate some data
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [datetime.now() for i in range(10)]})

# Substitution function
def update_date(row):
    if row['a'].year > 2023:
        return datetime.now()
    return row['a']

# Apply the function to the column
df['a'] = df.apply(update_date, axis=1)

print(df)
```

This is the output:

```
a
0 2023-08-02 15:33:39.915189
1 2023-08-02 15:33:39.915189
2 2023-08-02 15:33:39.915189
3 2023-08-02 15:33:39.915189
4 2023-08-02 15:33:39.915189
5 2023-08-02 15:33:39.915189
6 2023-08-02 15:33:39.915189
7 2023-08-02 15:33:39.915189
8 2023-08-02 15:33:39.915189
9 2023-08-02 15:33:39.915189
```